Not getting enough test coverage for Attachment and Email Attachment
I have currently have 76% coverage for my class, but would like to achieve higher code coverage. I passed the right parameter and even tried calling the attachpdf method in the test class and my test coverage is not going above 76%. I have method that creates the attachment and that did not help. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Below AttachPDF is the only method that is not getting coverage.
Class:
    global class FlowinvokedAndAttachPDF implements Process.Plugin { 


/<------------------------getting coverage-------------------->/
    String generatePDFfromVFpage = (String) request.inputParameters.get('generatePDFfromVFpage');
    String attachPDFToRecordID = (String) request.inputParameters.get('parenRecordId');
    String pdfAttachmentName = (String) request.inputParameters.get('pdfAttachmentName');
    String sourceIDforVFpage = (String) request.inputParameters.get('sourceRecordId');  
    emailTo = (String) request.inputParameters.get('emailTo'); 
    emailMessage = (String) request.inputParameters.get('emailMessage');  
    emailSubject = (String) request.inputParameters.get('emailSubject'); 
    
        
    Map<String,Object> result = new Map<String,Object>();
    CreateEmailBody(Id.valueOf(sourceIDforVFpage));
    AddRecipients(Id.valueOf(sourceIDforVFpage));
    AttachPDF(generatePDFfromVFpage, parenRecordId, pdfAttachmentName,sourceRecordId,emailTo,emailMessage,emailSubject);
    result.put('Status', aStatus);
    result.put('Error Message', anErrorDescription);
    
        return new Process.PluginResult(result); 
    } 

    global Process.PluginDescribeResult describe() {<->}

    public void CreateEmailBody(Id intakeEventId){<->}

    public void AddRecipients(id intakeEventId){<->}
    /<------------------------getting coverage-------------------->/

//Not getting any coverage
public void AttachPDF(String generatePDFfromVFpage ,String parenRecordId, String pdfAttachmentName,String sourceRecordId,
                                    String emailTo,String emailMessage,String emailSubject) {


Blob pdfAttachment;
    try {


        PageReference pdf = Page.Sample_Distribution_Report; // Sample_Distribution_Report is vf page
        pdf.getParameters().put('id',sourceRecordId );   
        pdfattachment = pdf.getContentAsPDF();

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.ParentId = parenRecordId;
        attach.Name = pdfAttachmentName;
        attach.Body = pdfAttachment;
        insert(attach);

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach1.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attach1.setFileName(pdfAttachmentName);     //this needs to be parameterized
        attach1.setInline(false);
        attach1.Body = pdfattachment;  


        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);

        String[] toAddresses_New = emailTo_New.split(';',100);
        if(toAddresses_New[0] != ''){
            //New email distribution
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail_New = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail_New.setToAddresses(toAddresses_New);
            mail_New.setSenderDisplayName('test@test.com');
            mail_New.setSubject(emailSubject_New);
            mail_New.setBccSender(false);
            mail_New.setUseSignature(false);
            mail_New.setHtmlBody(emailMessage_New);
            mail_New.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach1 });
            mail_New.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail_New });
        }

        aStatus = SUCCESS_CODE;
    } catch (Exception anException) {
        astatus = ERROR_CODE;
        anErrorDescription = anException.getMessage();
    }
    
   }    
}

Test Class:
@isTest
private class FlowCreateAndAttachVFPDF_Updated_Test {   
        static testmethod void FlowinvokedMethod() {
         
    
            Intake_Incident_Event__c event = createEvent2();
            Attachment newAttachment = createAttachment();
            //Intake_Incident__c newIncident = createIncident();
            
            FlowinvokedAndAttachPDF plugin = new FlowinvokedAndAttachPDF();
            Map<String,Object> inputParams = new Map<String,Object>();
            
            string eventId = event.Id;
            List <Intake_Incident_Event__c> eventQuery = [SELECT Id, Status__c, Bypass_Distribution__c, Involved_Party_Type__c,RecordType.Name, Name FROM Intake_Incident_Event__c WHERE Id =: eventId];
            string eventName = eventQuery[0].Name;
            List <Attachment> attach = [SELECT id,Name from Attachment WHERE ParentId =: eventId];
            string generatePDFfromVFpage = 'Sample_Distribution_Report';
            string parenRecordId = eventId;
            string pdfAttachmentName = eventName + '.pdf';
            string sourceRecordId = eventId;
            string emailTo = 'test@test.com';
            string emailMessage = 'test email message';
            string emailSubject = 'test email subject';
    
            Boolean byPassdistribution = event.Bypass_Distribution__c;
           
    
            
            InputParams.put('generatePDFfromVFpage', generatePDFfromVFpage);
            InputParams.put('emailMessage', emailMessage);
            InputParams.put('emailSubject', emailSubject);
            InputParams.put('sourceRecordId', sourceRecordId);
            InputParams.put('parenRecordId', parenRecordId);
            InputParams.put('Bypass_Distribution__c', byPassdistribution);
    
            plugin.AttachPDF( generatePDFfromVFpage , parenRecordId,  pdfAttachmentName, sourceRecordId,
                                             emailTo, emailMessage, emailSubject);
            Process.PluginRequest request = new Process.PluginRequest(inputParams);           
            
            plugin.invoke(request);
            Process.PluginDescribeResult result = plugin.describe();
        }
}


Can you highlight covered lines?

Commented the coverage lines. Thanks.

What I see is that AttachPDF method has 0 lines covered. Does your class fail during test run? It should, because otherwise I don't see how it isn't covered at all.

Thanks, Andrii. I have updated lines that are getting coverage from AttachedPDF method.

I still see the AttachPDF method has 0 lines covered.

For here onwards it is not getting coverage in my class,         Attachment attach = new Attachment();
attach.ParentId = parenRecordId;
attach.Name = pdfAttachmentName;
attach.Body = pdfAttachment;
insert(attach);
